# is there a way to add a fixed size to placed images in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation

I want to place hundreds of images in an InDesign project, I need all those images to have the same width when I place them.

is there a way to do that?

**EDIT**

I tried this way:

1. place the first image and set its size.
2. copy this image and put it every where you want an image to be placed.
3. then select the image boxes and place your new images.

this way all new images will be placed in the same box width size. this is a solution but it will not be that practical and that way I have to do a two step process..

Comment: Hi Ahmad Yousef, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I edited my question and added more information . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want something simpler than you already have it might be easier to batch resize the images outside of InDesign.

Within InDesign you could use Empty Frames as the placeholders (which is what they are)

[image]

Then Place and select all of the images you wish to place:

[image]

Then actually place them by clicking on the frames:

[image]

Finally, select all images and do Fit Content Proportionally to Frame (or whatever Fitting you desire):

[image]

Results:

[image]

But again, since you've got hundreds of images it would probably be easier to batch resize them before placing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Ryan, This was clear, I guess the best way is like what you said at the end, batch resizing them..but this may reduce their quality

Answer (score 1):

To place a number of graphics all resized to the same percentage (size) create a master page with a graphic box to your required dimensions, place a graphic into it and resize to your required size/percentage (say 50%) and position. Delete the graphic (not the box).

When you now add a new document page using that master page and place a graphic into its graphic box, hey presto! The image is resized to 50% on import.

I needed to import a large PDF document that was created at A4 page size and I had to reduce to 50%, this worked great. Once placed I just needed to make minor positional adjustments with the arrow keys. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ian, welcome to GD.SE. I edited your answer to make it look more clear, please next time use some paragraphs, it improves readability.